# See the XML of a .xls file?

Tags: xml, file, xls

Is there a way to see the XML behind a .xls file? It doesn't seem to be a .zip file like .xlsx files, so there's nothing to unzip, and the data itself is all sorts of weird characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no XML behind it.  It's a binary format known as MCDF (Microsoft Compound Document File) and dates back years (maybe decades?).  This is the same format used in all sorts of Office applications, such as .doc, .msg, etc.  It's composed of various *streams* that represent different parts of the file.  I've written some code that parses this data, but it's not for the faint of heart.  I found the [OpenMCDF](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openmcdf/) library pretty helpful for getting at the individual streams.

In the case of XLS, you'd probably be best using the Excel ODBC driver to read the data similar to working with a database.